# kubernetes mysql chown operation not permitted

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am currently experimenting with Kubernetes and have installed a small cluster on ESX infra I had running here locally. I installed two slave nodes with a master node using Project Atomic with Fedora. The cluster is all installed fine and seems to be running. However I first want to get a MySQL container up and running, but no matter what I try i cannot get it to run.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels: 
    name: mysql
spec: 
  containers: 
    - resources:
       limits :
          cpu: 0.5
      image: mysql:5.6
      name: mysql
      env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: myPassw0rd
      ports: 
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
      volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
  volumes:
    - name: mysql-persistent-storage
      nfs:
        server: 10.0.0.2
        path: "/export/mysql"
```

For the volume I already tried all kinds of solutions, I tried using persistent volume with and without claim. I tried using host volume and emptyDir, but I always end up with this error when the container starts:

chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/': Operation not permitted

I must be doing something stupid, but no idea what to do here?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ok it seems I can answer my own question, the problem was lying in the NFS share that was being used as the persistent volume. I had it set to 'squash_all' in the export but it needs to have a 'no_root_squash' to allow root in case of docker container to chown on the nfs bound volume.

Comment: Unfortunately the story for using NFS for dockerhub images is not great, since many images try to chown in this way, and using `no_root_squash` is not recommended, because it means the NFS client runs operations as root on the NFS server.  Doubly unfortunately, I don't have a great way to avoid this for Dockerhub images at the moment.

Comment: What does this look like form a docker-compose setup perspective?

Comment: Thanks Renze de Vries! This helped!

Comment: **no_root_squash** on NFS clients is dangerous read [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Security_Guide/s2-server-nfs-noroot.html). You better have valid reason for this flag (root access), otherwise sys admin and security expert will eat you alive :P

Comment: I ran into this issue while trying to use `nfs` mounts for local Docker development on a Mac due to Docker's performance issues with volumes on Macs. It seems like the warnings around `no_root_squash` are for public servers rather than development machines, right?

Answer (score 8):

I solved this problem other way. I had an argument with system administrator regarding allowing root access to exported NFS directory on NFS client machine(s). He has valid security reasons for not setting it such [reason one](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Security_Guide/s2-server-nfs-noroot.html) and [reason two](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/nfs-serverconfig#idm140189752574704) -read **no_root_squash** section.

At the end I didn't have to request **no_root_squash**. This is what I did to make mysql pod running without compromising security.

### Step 1

Exec into pod's container runing mysql image. `kubectl exec -it -n <namespace> <mysql_pod> -- bash`

### Step 2

Obtain **uid** (999) and **gid** (999) of **mysql** user. `cat /etc/passwd | tail -n` or `id mysql`. **mysql** username can be found in 2nd instruction specified in [Dockerfile](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker-library/mysql/3dfa7a3c038f342b9dec09fa85247bef69ae2349/8.0/Dockerfile)

### Step 3

Change permission to the directory that holds content of **/var/lib/mysql** of docker container. This is more likely the directory specified in your **PersistentVolume**. *This command is executed on host machine, not in the Pod!!!*

```
# PerisistentVolume
...
nfs:
    path: /path/to/app/mysql/directory
    server: nfs-server
```

Run `chown 999:999 -r /path/to/app/mysql/directory`

### Step 4

Finally after everything is set, deploy your MySQL Pod (deployment, replica set or whatever you are using).

Comment: I ran into similar issue while trying to run Cassandra Docker image on Minikube on Mac.  chown 999:999 ... saved the day!  Thanks Lukasz Dynowski

Comment: Recently I've deployed more services, mongodb, rabbitmq etc..The same error occurred, after recreating my pods (scaling my pods to 0, and back to 1). Somehow, after recreating the pods permissions for some of the files are lost. I had to run ` chown 999:999 -r  /path/to/app/service/directory` and problem was fixed. So this solution applies not only to msql. Cheers!

Comment:  saved my day. my /etc/export is as such:
/mnt/usb-hdd *(rw,insecure,sync,all_squash,anonuid=999,anongid=999,no_subtree_check)

Answer (score 4):

This can also be resolved by having mysql container run with the same uid that owns the nfs volume using Kubernetes' securityContext definition.

```
containers:
- name: mysql
  image: ...
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 2015
    allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
```

Here the *2015* should be replaced with whatever ownership is on the nfs path.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by specifying the `fsGroup` in pod securityContext. The `fsGroup` defined the `gid` that mounted directories should have. With this, you are able to make the mounted directory owned by the user running the process.

**Pod spec**

```
...
spec:
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 1003
    runAsUser: 1003
    runAsGroup: 1003
```