# chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/': Operation not permitted in start pods in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

When I start my mysql 5.7 pods in kubernetes v1.15.2, the logs shows like this:

```
2020-05-30 13:08:04+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.30-1debian10 started.
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/': Operation not permitted
```

this is my mysql yaml define:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: apollo-mysql
  namespace: sre
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
  clusterIP: None
---
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: apollo-mysql
  namespace: sre
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: apollo-mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: apollo-mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.7
        name: mysql
        env:
          # Use secret in real usage
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: gfwge4LucnXwfefewegLwAd29QqJn4
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: apollo-mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: apollo-mysql-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: apollo-mysql-pv-claim
```

and this is my pv define:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs-apollo-mysql-pv1
  namespace: sre
  labels:
    alicloud-pvname: apollo-mysql-data-db
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  storageClassName: apollo-mysql-data-db
  mountOptions:
    - vers=4.0
    - noresvport
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  nfs:
    server: "192.168.64.237"
    path: "/mnt/data/apollodb/apollopv"
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
```

and I already change the mod to 777 like this:

```
chmod 777 /mnt/data/apollodb/apollopv
```

so where is the problem and what should I do to fix this? I check the selinux status and it is disabled.

```
[miao@meowk8sslave3 apollodb]$ /usr/sbin/sestatus -v
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

This is my nfs exports define:

```
/mnt/data/apollodb/apollopv *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

Comment: I was able to run the MySQL deployment volume as `emptyDir:{}`. So, the image itself looks fine. can you check whether SELinux is enabled on NFS host?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878574/kubernetes-mysql-chown-operation-not-permitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yaml you have provided is missing PVC, which specifies the `storageClass` to be mounted.

It looks like you are trying to mount an external NFS (with some cloud provider perhaps), in which case you need to have `nfs-utils` installed, and do `mount -t nfs 192.168.64.237:/entrypoint /mnt/...`.

Your PV says `/mnt/data/apollodb/apollopv`, which should be the entrypoint to the nfs server, and not where it is going to be mounted in your filesystem.

To make this work, get yourself an nfs server (get the IP address and the entrypoint; say 192.168.64.237:/nfs), then mount it in your pod as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: apollo-mysql
  namespace: sre
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: apollo-mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: apollo-mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.7
        name: mysql
        env:
          # Use secret in real usage
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: gfwge4LucnXwfefewegLwAd29QqJn4
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: apollo-mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: apollo-mysql-persistent-storage
        nfs:
          server: 192.168.64.237
          path: "/nfs"
```

You won't need the storage class, the PVC and the PV. Everything you need is in the pod, and externally you have the nfs server.